# Magento sorting collection only sorting first 20 products

Tags: collection, sorting

I'm passing a collection to a method that will conditionally apply sorting to it.  However, it seems that only 20 of the total products are being sorted, the rest, are unsorted and lay at the end of the bulk sorted section.  Why is this?  Below is the the conditional:

```
protected function sortProducts($collection)
{
    switch ($this->getOrder()) {
        case 'product group':
            return $collection->addAttributeToSort('price', 'asc');
    ...
    ...
    }
}
```

Below is the resultant log of the product collection (note this is a new products collection containing 25 products in total).

> 2015-01-29T21:53:38+00:00 DEBUG (7): SELECT 1 AS `status`,
>   `e`.`entity_id`, `e`.`type_id`, `e`.`attribute_set_id`,
>   `cat_index`.`position` AS `cat_index_position`, `price_index`.`price`,
>   `price_index`.`tax_class_id`, `price_index`.`final_price`,
>   IF(price_index.tier_price IS NOT NULL, LEAST(price_index.min_price,
>   price_index.tier_price), price_index.min_price) AS `minimal_price`,
>   `price_index`.`min_price`, `price_index`.`max_price`,
>   `price_index`.`tier_price`, `e`.`name`, `e`.`short_description`,
>   `e`.`price`, `e`.`special_price`, `e`.`special_from_date`,
>   `e`.`special_to_date`, `e`.`small_image`, `e`.`thumbnail`,
>   `e`.`news_from_date`, `e`.`news_to_date`, `e`.`url_key`,
>   `e`.`required_options`, `e`.`image_label`, `e`.`small_image_label`,
>   `e`.`thumbnail_label`, `e`.`msrp_enabled`,
>   `e`.`msrp_display_actual_price_type`, `e`.`msrp`, `e`.`tax_class_id`,
>   `e`.`price_type`, `e`.`weight_type`, `e`.`price_view`,
>   `e`.`shipment_type`, `e`.`links_purchased_separately`,
>   `e`.`links_exist`, `e`.`giftcard_amounts`, `e`.`allow_open_amount`,
>   `e`.`open_amount_min`, `e`.`open_amount_max` FROM
>   `catalog_product_flat_1` AS `e`  INNER JOIN
>   `catalog_category_product_index` AS `cat_index` ON
>   cat_index.product_id=e.entity_id AND cat_index.store_id='1' AND
>   cat_index.visibility IN(2, 4) AND cat_index.category_id = '2'  INNER
>   JOIN `catalog_product_index_price` AS `price_index` ON
>   price_index.entity_id = e.entity_id AND price_index.website_id = '1'
>   AND price_index.customer_group_id = 0 WHERE (((((e.news_from_date <=
>   '2015-01-29 23:59:59') OR (e.news_from_date IS null))))) AND
>   (((((e.news_to_date >= '2015-01-29 00:00:00') OR (e.news_to_date IS
>   null))))) AND ((`e`.`news_from_date` IS not null) OR
>   (`e`.`news_to_date` IS not null)) ORDER BY `e`.`news_from_date` desc,
>   `price_index`.`min_price` asc

Comment: One way to debug this is to look at the returned SQL to confirm that the sorting is as you describe. Try logging out the query using `$collection->getSelect()->__toString()` If you can then paste that output with any other collection manipulation that might be done before the return ( passed into the method ) or after in the calling method I can try and help more.

Comment: attached is the resultant tostring of the collection

Comment: Try $collection->getSelect()->limit(100); to see if it changes. If it does ill check how to remove the limit.

Comment: To remove the limit `$collection->setPageSize(false);`
Try running the query in a MySQL client and try updating the sort `ORDER BY` as currently its sorting on `news_from_date` desc and the n`price` asc perhaps the data you have is what makes this appear to be an issue and not the collection query that is being generated.

Comment: @JamesCowie  Removing the `news_from_date` sort and only using the `price` sort seems to have cleared things up, thanks.  Now time to reconfigure this collection sort.  If you create an answer I'll gladly accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your collection is being sorted as expected however there is another `SORT` also being applied `news_from_date` that gives the appearance of incorrect results.

#### Steps to debug are:

Output the SQL query using `$collection->getSelect()->__toString()` or via MyTop / alternatives.

Running the SQL query in a MySQL client we can inspect what could be causing the issues. In this case it was the final `SORT` condition where the collection is being sorted on news from date desc and then price asc.

#### Fix

Now we know that there is another sort being applied to the collection we can update the block method creating this collection to only apply the sorting we require.